# Heat Losses from water pan due to vaporisation before boiling

Tags: thermodynamics, water, diffusion, evaporation

I'm studying heat transfer from an electric heater to a cooking pan (Stainless steel) filled with water; specifically, my problem is related to water vaporisation, as I've already found good models to predict radiative and convection losses.
The point is that vaporisation losses are easy to calculate after the water reaches the boiling point, as mass of water vaporised times enthalpy of vaporisation of water at atmospheric pressure (which is 2257 kJ/kg). But what happens before boiling?
My experiments show that a considerable amount of water already evaporates starting from a temperature of 70°C. In fact, it is well known that water evaporates even at ambient temperature due to mass diffusion, and as the temperature increases the rate of evaporation is also increased.
But since the water is not saturated, I guess I cannot calculate this loss by means of any enthalpy of vaporisation. How should I calculate the heat removed from the pan by the water molecules escaping from the upper surface at temperatures lower than boiling?

Thank you very much

Comment: search on evaporation rate

Answer (score 1):

At the interface, the air is saturated with water vapor at the interface temperature.  So you know the partial pressure of the water vapor at the interface (if you know the interface temperature).  The water then diffuses into the room air above, where the bulk partial pressure of water is less than the saturation vapor pressure at the interface.  There is also convective transport of the air away from the interface, and this air carries the water vapor away from the interface.  So this has to be included in your model.  There is a heat flux from the bulk of the water to the interface (i.e., at temperature gradient in the water below the interface), and there is a heat flux in the air above away from the interface.  The difference between these two heat fluxes is equal to the heat of vaporization times the vaporization rate.  There may also be natural convection currents in the water below the interface to enhance the rate of heat transfer.  This is just a rough outline of what is happening, but all these things need to be considered in formulating a model of the heat and mass transfer in your system.

Comment: Actually I have experimentally measured the evaporation rate of my water surface, so I know it. The problem is that it is not fitting weel my theoretical model.
I tried a mass transport model both considerng or not convective effects, and in both cases the theoretically estimated rate of evaporation is much lower than what experimentally recorded. Do you have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: It's very hard to answer this question without knowing more of the details.  Are you saying that the experimentally measured evaporation rate is higher than the power provided by the heater divided by the heat of vaporization?

Comment: No, I'm trying to estimate the rate of evaporation by means of mass diffusion theory. It should be a function of diffusion coefficient, vapour concentration (both dependent on T), boundary layer height, surface area, and ambient relative humidity. It should not be directly affected by the heater power, which just affects the time needed to reach a certain dT, and thus the total mass evaporated.
But what I obtain from this model is roughly one order of magnitude less than what emerging from experimental data

Comment: So you are looking at the transient situation and estimating the cumulative amount of evaporation up to time t?

Comment: In my theoretical model yes, I'm doing so. But pay attention: I'm considering the transient situation at different temperatures (30-40-50-60-70 °C). So the "cumulative amount" from 30 to 70 degrees is estimated multiplying the rate of vaporisation of each temperature interval for the corresponding time interval, and summing all of them.
As for the experimental data, I get the cumulative amount vaporised from 30 to 70 degrees simply weighing the pot before and after this temperature interval. It should be equal but is bigger by one order of magnitude.

Comment: Tell a little more about the model.  Is it basically as follows:  The partial pressure at the interface is the equilibrium vapor pressure at the liquid temperature.  The molar concentration at the interface is determined from the ideal gas law, based on the temperature and pressure at the interface.  The evaporation rate is equal to the mass transfer coefficient times the concentration difference between the interface and room air.

Comment: Exactly as you said; the concentration in room air is calculated by means of relative humidity. I've tried to force the model (by means of a solver) to obtain the same result as experimental data. It returns a value of 0 for relative humidity and 4,7 mm for the boundary layer, which instead I assumed to be as high as the distance of the water surface from the upper limit of the pot.
Also, a value of 0 for the relative humidity is not really acceptable since I'm working in a basement

Comment: Your estimate of the boundary layer thickness is way too high.  There is bound to be a lot of natural convection above the water surface, particularly at the higher temperatures, reducing the BL thickness.  I'm guessing that  the mass transfer correlations don't give a boundary layer thickness anywhere near the distance between the water surface and the rim.

Comment: Ok, I'm happy to hear that the boundary layer is too high because reducing it can improve my estimate.
But how much should its thickness be, then? I cannot put it at zero, otherwise my evap.rate would be infinite.
As you said,the evaporation rate is equal to the mass diffusion coefficient times the concentration difference between the interface and room air, times water surface area, divided by the BL thickness.

Comment: It will take a little researching the mass transfer and heat transfer literature to get an estimate of the mass transfer coefficient (or BL thickness).  Basically you have  natural convection mass transfer and heat transfer from a horizontal surface.  I would start with Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot and Mass Transfer Operations by Treybel.  There may also be some forced convection currents in your basement that could have an effect.  Whatever you find, it's not going to be super-accurate.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, heat loss due to vaporization happens at any temperature. You can reasonably assume that the air right above the liquid is trying to remain saturated - and if you put a lid on the pot, that will indeed be the case. In that case, the heat loss due to vaporization will be quite low.

If you don't have a lid on the pot, the rate of heat loss due to vaporization becomes extremely hard to calculate, because it depends on the relative saturation of the air at the interface, which depends on the details of the air flow. Tables have been published for rates of heat loss as a function of wind velocity; see for example [my earlier answer on heating swimming pools](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/117298/26969) for some details. This shows that the rate of evaporation strongly depends on wind velocity: you are familiar with the concept of *wind chill* of which this is one manifestation.

The actual heat per unit mass removed can be determined from tables of heat of vaporization as a function of temperature - see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization from which I reproduce this figure:

[image]

This shows a clear dependence of the heat of vaporization on temperature: not surprising, since you expect a molecule that escapes the liquid at a lower temperature to carry a relatively higher fraction of energy with it. I fitted (by eye) a straight line to the data between 260 and 360 K (roughly from freezing to boiling); the overlay (zoomed in) looked like this:

[image]

The coefficients of that straight line were

$$y = 3195 - 2.5T$$

which gives a value of 2262 J/g at 373 K - pretty close to various published values. I recommend using this relationship to estimate the heat of vaporization at temperatures below boiling - it should be close. The main problem is knowing how much liquid evaporates, and that's much harder.

Comment: I assume wind speed is zero since my model refers to a controlled laboratory setting; my problem is with the heat of vaporization: I also have tables showing the correlation between heat of vaporization and temperature, but I'm guessing if using the concept of "heat of vaporization" for a liquid which is sub-cooled (lower temperature than transition phase) is correct!
In fact, tables do not correlate heat of vaporization with "temperature" of water, but rather with "saturation temperature" of water [...continues]

Comment: [...follows] For a pressure of 1 bar, saturation temperature is 373,15K and heat of vap. is 2257 kj/kg. Tables show, for example, that at 300K heat of vaporization is 2438 kj/kg, but that means 300K SATURATION temperature, which requires a 0,035 bars pressure! If we are working always at 1 bar pressure, there is no heat of vaporization before transition phase, there is ony sub-cooled liquid

Comment: You are overthinking this. The _vapor pressure_ will be less than one atmosphere but at a given temperature the air will be saturated with just a little bit of moisture. It just happens that at 373.15 K that pressure is one atmosphere so water will boil; but air can be saturated (100% relative humidity) at temperatures below the boiling point.

Comment: Ok, then is reasonable to use the heat of vaporisation. Thank you